# Aligning image, button, and animated text using CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have this front page and I'm trying to have the button align towards the middle like below the text, but I've tried adding margins and it won't move. Any tips?

[image: Here is the photo]

```css
   .parallax {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #C4CBCA;
      background-attachment: scroll; /*fixed: image scrolls; scroll: image stays*/
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .create {
      background-color: #a4cdd1;
      color: white;
      min-width: 214px;
      border: none;
      height: 43px;
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
      font: 700 15px Lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 13px 15px 10px;
      /*margin-left: 300px;*/
      /*margin-top: 10px;*/
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    
    #animated-example {
      font: 700 30px Lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #5D5F71;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 200px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .animated {
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes lightSpeedIn {
      0% { transform: translateX(100%) skewX(-30deg); opacity: 0; }
      60% { transform: translateX(-20%) skewX(30deg); opacity: 1; }
      80% { transform: translateX(0%) skewX(-15deg); opacity: 1; }
      100% { transform: translateX(0%) skewX(0deg); opacity: 1; }
    }
    
    .lightSpeedIn {
      animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    .animated.lightSpeedIn {
      animation-duration: 1s;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>front page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="front.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="parallax">
          <div id="animated-example" class="animated lightSpeedIn">
            <p>SOME TEXT HERE</p>
          </div>
          <div class="photo">
          <img src="macmockup.png" style="width:675px; height:675px; margin-left:20px; margin-top:15px;">
          </div>
          <div class="create">
          <a href="#" class="button">Create Template</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle for this to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whats killing you here is the float right it is overriding anything you add after that.

Now i don't think this is the best solution but if you remove the float you can then add whatever margin left you need to get the button to move.

something to look into for you would be bootstrap, it is a much cleaner way to format a lot of this http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: It was actually the float that was stopping it from moving. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this Remove float: right from .create

```
<div class="create_wrapper">
  <div class="create">
    <a href="#" class="button">Create Template</a>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
.create {
  background-color: #a4cdd1;
  color: white;
  min-width: 214px;
  border: none;
  height: 43px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 700 15px Lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 13px 15px 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.create_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to align `.create` to center if you want it in the middle.

```
.create{ text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

add following css on your style:

```
.parallax {
    position: relative;
}
.create {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

check live http://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/qaAjgY